# About the turning point in a sequence of random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,..$ be a sequence of random variables drawn i.i.d. Let $N$ be the random variable which given a sequence outputs the smallest $n$ such that $X_{n} \geq X_{n-1}$. What is $\mathbb{E}[N]$?

---

On solution I was reading says that we can calculate $P[N \geq k] = P[ X_1 \geq X_2 \geq..\geq X_{k-1} ] =  \frac{1}{(k-1)!}$ because apparently one can equivalently think of being given $k-1$ numbers and this is the probability of them being arranged in decreasing order.

I don't understand this argument at all. Even the first equality above is not clear to me! Also $N$'s domain is the space of all (infinite) sequences of numbers. This above calculation seems to totally miss the fact that the sequence itself was chosen randomly.

One closeby case that I can think of is $P[N = k] = \frac{1}{(k-1)!}$ being true for a given set of numbers when the randomization is only over their arrangement. But here there is a randomization over the sequences it self.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(N=k)=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}$ is clearly wrong, since then $\mathbb{P}(N=1)=\mathbb{P}(N=2)=1$.

Comment: I think I was reading the solution slightly wrong. I have edited what they exactly said. It anyway still makes no sense to me!

Comment: Are the $X_i$ continuous random variables?

Comment: Yes. The question states that they come from a continuous distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Because the $X_i$ are continuous random variables, the sequence $(X_1,\dots,X_{k-1})$ consists of distinct real numbers almost surely, and all $(k-1)!$ orderings of these real numbers are equally likely because the $X_i$ are i.i.d (so the joint law is symmetric). Since only one of the orderings gives us the outcome $N\geq k$, it follows that $\mathbb{P}(N\geq k)=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}$.

Here is an example when $k=3$ in the situation when the $X_i$ have pdf $f$: We have
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_1\geq X_2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^xf_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}(y)\;dydx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^xf(x)f(y)\;dydx $$
and on the other hand
$$\mathbb{P}(X_2\geq X_1)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^yf_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}(y)\;dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^yf(x)f(y)\;dxdy $$
These two integrals have the same value (since the only thing that's different is the variables of integration) so the two probabilities are the same. The argument for larger $k$ is essentially the same.

Comment: Can you actually derive this expression from first principles? I don't understand many parts of this argument. (a) what is this "almost surely" thing here? (2) How does the above argument take into account the fact that these $k$ numbers are randomly chosen? If I was given $k$ fixed numbers and the randomization was over the arrangement alone then I might have gotten the same answer for $P(N = k \vert X_{k} > X_{k-1} )$. right? (3) Since you are counting $N \geq k$ why don't the events greater than $k+1$ matter?

Comment: Let me include an example in the case $k=3$. You do agree that $\{N\geq k\}=\{X_1\geq X_2\geq\dots\geq X_{k-1}\}$, right?

Comment: No. I can't understand this equality either. I can at best agree to a statement like, $P[N =k] = P[ X_1 \geq X_2 \geq X_3 ..\geq X_{k-1} \leq X_k]$ and there is no way to split the event on the RHS into products.

Comment: $N\geq k$ means that $N$ is not equal to one of $1,2\dots,k-1$. This means that $X_1\geq X_2$ since $N\neq 1$, $X_2\geq X_3$ since $N\neq 2$, and so on, finally $X_{k-2}\geq X_{k-1}$ since $N\neq k-1$.